# SQL Server Replication How to keep primary key schema at publisher

Tags: sql-server, replication, schema, transaction-log

I have implemented Transactional replication and want to have similar schema structure at both subscriber and publisher end. But while creating the publication, `Not For Replication` appears in front of Primary key, I got some guidance from this forum, that if I set `sync_type` to `initialize from backup` it can be achievable

So, I followed instructions from various blogs like [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2386/initialize-sql-server-replication-using-a-database-backup/) and [this](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-transactional-replication-how-to-reinitialize-a-subscription-using-a-sql-server-database-backup/),but, nothing seems to work as the issue reappears, Am I doing something wrong? is it even possible?